# how to decorate a zend navigation menu?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-navigation

i have this menu:

```
 $menu['talent'] = array(
                 array('id'     => 'welcome', 
                       'label'  => 'My Profile', 
                       'uri'    => '/profile/,
                       'class'  => 'navlink'
                       )
                 ),
                 array('id' => 'welcome', 
                       'label' => 'My Profile', 
                       'class'  => 'navlink',
                       'uri' => '/profile/
                 ),             
    );
```

this will end up looking like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="navlink">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="navlink">My Profile</a></li>
<ul>
```

how can i change the `ul` into a `div` and also the `li` into something else?

any idas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to accomplish this I would use one of these two methods:

### Using a View Helper and overload menu()

In order to overload `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu`, you could write you own helper, register it and make it extends `Zend_View_Helper_Navigation_Menu`. In your helper, you can overload the method you want such as `_renderMenu()` and **make it renders `<p>` instead of `<li>`** for example. In your View Helper, you would have to return the parent::menu() or something like this.

Finally, you have to register this new View Helper using:

```
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_ROOT . '/library/My/View/Helper/Navigation', 'My_View_Helper_');
```

### Using a partial script

This one seems to me a little bit longer, but it worth a try.
Basically, you need to set a partial script to your navigation using `setPartial()` method and  you menu will be rendered through this partial.

```
<?= $this->navigation()->menu()->setMaxDepth(2)->setPartial('partials/_nav.phtml')->render() . PHP_EOL; ?>
```

Afterwards, in your _nav.phtml you can render your menu as you wish. From this partial, you can access the menu variables using `$this->container`. Then, you can iterate through each page of your container, and display what you want.

I know all of this seem pretty complicate for such a simple task, but unfortunately this is the only solution. Does anyone have a better idea?